# Assign variable to struct member

Tags: c, struct, char, var

I have created a struct with a char variable in it. I want to assign a string value to it when using it inside of a method and then print it. I have been looking around but can't find a valid answer, but can't find what I'm doing wrong. Why am I getting the error below?

Here is what I have tried:

```
struct node{
    char *val;
    struct node *first;
    struct node *last;
};


void main(){
      struct node *new_node;
new_node =(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
   new_node.val = "a";
   printf("%s",new_node.val);
}
```

I get the error:

```
request for member 'val' in something not a structure or union
```

Comment: You need to use `->` not `.` since it is a pointer.

Comment: You should also use "%c" instead of "%s" - "%s" is expecting a pointer to an array of characters which are NULL terminated. If you provide "%s" with a character printf will treat that character as a pointer which will either crash or output some garbage.

Comment: I made an edit...I as supposed to write char *val

Comment: How can you be calling `malloc` outside of any function?  Did you reorder that line with the definition of `main`?

Comment: C doesn't have methods...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new_node` should be accessed as a pointer and not an instance.
try `new_node->val` instead of `new_node.val`

**response to edited question**
As you have changed from `char val` to `char *val` you will need additional processing:

1. allocate memory for `*val` : `new_node->val=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char))`
2. assignment will need to dereference the pointer : `*(new_node->val)="a"`
3. Print statement should also dereference the pointer : `printf("%c",*(new_node->val))`
4. you should free the `val` pointer before freeing `new_node`: `free(new_node->val)`

Comment: as mentioned by thisisdog, you will have additional errors once you resolve your current problem. Use '%c' when displaying characters and '%s' for displaying strings (null terminated array of characters)

Comment: And be careful when assigning string to your data. malloc newnode->val (using the strlen +1) and then use strcpy to assign. Then, you won't have any problem printing val as %s)

Answer (score 0):

new_node.val should be replaced with new_node->val. since new_node is a pointer. Keep in mind that new_node->val (often refereed as the arrow operator) is the shorthand for (*new_node).val.

Also i believe you can write:

```
node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
```

For easier reading and cleaner code since malloc will just return a pointer to a given memory address. Use -Wall or other warning flags when you compilate your program to experience less logical errors or seg faults.